React no renderiza los archivos por defecto que se instalan con VIte
Creo un proyecto con "npm create vite@latest", luego creo los package de Node con "npm install". Levanto el servidor local de Vite con "npm run dev", abro en el navegador "http://localhost:5173/", pero no se renderiza el contenido  de App.jsx (el archivo de ejemplo que crea Vite al instalarse). Se carga index.html, pero no renderiza el contenido de <div id="root"></div>.
En dev tools me sale este error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
